# How to send electronic TOEFL scores to institutions?

Tags: toefl

[image]

This is the paper result, right?(I just randomly entered a university) So...how can I let ETS send them the electronic result after the score had come out?...0.0

Answer (score 3):

Firstly choose "Order Score Reports, then select "TOEFL Services"
[image]

After that click the "Send Additional Score Report(s) to Institutions" and choose the test you want to send and then look up the institutions information. You will need to pay 19$ per report.